# HTML parser by perl script

Tags: html, perl, parsing, html-parsing, html-tree

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new; 

$tree->parse_file("sample.html");

foreach my $anchor ($tree->find("p")) {

  print $anchor->as_text, "\n";

}
```

my code is not printing any output. `$tree->find("p")` is returning NULL.

Comment: Please ensure that the file exists in the same directory as the script and that it has p elements. Your script ran fine for me outputting the 4 p tags that my sample.html had

Comment: file is in the same directory as the sample.html and it has <p> tags. But still it does not return anything.

Comment: What does `$tree->dump` print?

Answer (score 0):

You're not opening the file, or it's completely unparseable.

Try something like:

```
my $file = shift(@ARGV) or die "No filename given";
$tree->parse_file($file) or die "Unable to open $file";
```

That way you can check which it is.

Your script worked fine when I had the following for sample.html

```
<html>
<head><title>test file</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>First para</p>
    <p>Second para</p>
    <div>
        <P>Third para</P>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```